# Retrieve image from database and display in label

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, sqlexception

I am having one image named `P100.jpg`. I am resizing it and it is converted into `ZP100.png`. I am storing it into database MySQL, by insert query.

```
    File imageFile = new File("F:\\POSTERS\\Roses\\ZP100.png");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);

    String insertImage = "insert into image values(?,?)";
    prestmt = con.prepareStatement(insertImage);
    prestmt.setInt(1,4);
    prestmt.setBinaryStream(2, fis, fis.available());
    result = prestmt.executeUpdate();
```

Now I want to retrieve that image and display on a form by assigning it to a label.

```
    String selectImage = "select img from image";
    prestmt = con.prepareStatement(selectImage);
```

But it's giving me exception as

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs
```

For assigning image to a label I have:

```
    image.setText("ZP100.png");
```

I know, it cannot work. Please help me to recode this.

Comment: anybody can please help me......

Answer (score 0):

First error must be at this:

```
result = prestmt.executeUpdate();
```

I fear you have declared `result` with type `ResultSet`.
And when you are assigning an `int`, the return type of `executeUpdate()`, to `result`
obviously an `SQLException` is raised.

Modify above statement like this:

```
int insertResult = prestmt.executeUpdate();
```

And you should get a success on it.

***Suggestion***:

> *prestmt.setBinaryStream( 2, fis, **fis.available()** );*

Don't depend o[`available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) method if you want to `read` content from a stream.
It is just an *estimate* and won't guarantee you that you can read till the end of stream.

Instead use the other signature of the `setBinaryStream` method like:
[`setBinaryStream( int parameterIndex, InsputStream is )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29)
Javadoc says, *`The data will be read from the stream as needed until end-of-file is reached.`*, meaning you need not read it explicitly.
With the change, your statement would look like:

> ***prestmt.setBinaryStream( 2, fis );***

---

**Image**:
I have not worked much on Java GUI and images.
But can suggest you to refer to some solutions at:

1. *[Add Image to Button](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/AddImagetoButton.htm)*
2. *[Label with Image](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LabelwithImage.htm)*